# Why for X=1 probability mass function and cummulative density function differ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

Working on Poisson Distribution, Probability mass function works on discrete values and Cummulative Density Function adds them up (This is what I know correct me if I am wrong please). Since they will differ from each other in values why for X = 1 both have different probabilities? It starts from there so why they are different?

```
x= np.arange(1,10,1)
y = poisson.pmf(x,4.6)
print(y)
```

**Output:** [**0.04623844** 0.10634842 0.16306758 0.18752772 0.1725255  0.13226955
 0.08691999 0.04997899 0.02554482]

```
x= np.arange(1,10,1)
y = poisson.cdf(x,4.6)
print(y)
```

**Output:** [**0.05629028** 0.1626387  0.32570628 0.513234   0.6857595  0.81802905 0.90494904 0.95492804 0.98047286]

First Values are different. Please Explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake, Poisson distribution is defined on the whole positive number line, from 0 to infinity. You forgot to include the 0 in your calculations.

```
> dpois(0:10,4.6)
 [1] 0.01005184 0.04623844 0.10634842 0.16306758 0.18752772 0.17252550 0.13226955 0.08691999 0.04997899 0.02554482 0.01175062

> ppois(0:10,4.6)
 [1] 0.01005184 0.05629028 0.16263870 0.32570628 0.51323400 0.68575950 0.81802905 0.90494904 0.95492804 0.98047286 0.99222347
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting zero:

```
>>> poisson.cdf(1, 4.6)
0.056290280169948054

>>> poisson.pmf(0, 4.6) + poisson.pmf(1, 4.6)
0.056290280169948075
```

So the first element in your `cdf()` output is the cumulative of `x=0` & `x=1`